# Why I am getting this error message when I run react js project first time in my system?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, npm-start

1. When I run `npm start`, I get this error message:

> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'

Comment: try run `npm cache clean`

Comment: \AppData\Local\Temp\ did you try removing everything in the `npm` folder?

Comment: I didn't find any npm file \AppData\Local\Temp\

Comment: Did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 19):

follow the below steps:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder.
2. run `npm install` .
3. run `npm cache clean` .

*first 2 steps worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. The first two steps worked for me as well.

Comment: However, it started throwing same error again after I imported newly installed component in my code. And it is not going away even though I performed step 1 and 2 again.

Comment: The reason for the error thrown would majorly be caused by the use of an outdated versions of packages (dependencies). So, the best shot would be to follow the above 3 steps or upgrade every single dependency in the project (check inside package.json)

Comment: Yeah, I was missing some dependencies in package.json and it started working fine. Do you know why `npm cache clean` thorws this error `npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.`

Comment: There could be many reasons for that. It may occur due to npm didn't download properly, permission problem (try executing cmd with `sudo`), or It could be (most obiviously) due to not clearing cache properly (use `npm cache clean --force`) in that case. Also, the npm>5 have some upgrades, if you'll try removing and installing npm again, then this error may not occur.

Comment: Yeah, I had to use `npm cache clean --force` but whenever I checked the status using `npm verify` (I hope I wrote the command correctly), it always showed some 0MB bytes, even before  running `npm cache clean --force`. I wonder if any cache is getting cleared or not.

Answer (score 3):

Delete `node_modules` folder and then run:

```
npm install && npm clean-install react-scripts
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by installing the *chart.js: 2.5.0* dependency.
The issue with my code is that I was using *react-chartjs-2* dependency and in order to use it, I needed to install *chart.js*.

Note that I had to install it manually. `npm i` wasn't working.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

running

```
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

Solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Then I was importing a package that I didn't yet install.
So make sure you have installed all the packages that you are using in the import statements at the top of your React component.

Comment: fair, I understand that, but wouldnt the error be higher up at all to where we could get more of a "cannot find module `x` in `index.js` etc"? Makes things hard to catch from an error perspective

Answer (score 1):

deleting `node_modules` folder and then running:

```
npm install
npm cache clean
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with *nativscript/angular* router.

Problem was bad import. I mean deep import like `@nativescript/angular/router`.

I changed it to `@nativescript/angular` because there is no more deep imports.

Maybe it is a similar problem with your react-router.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You're probably working in a Linux environment. If it is so, before running the start script, you need to switch the terminal to sudo user.

This approach fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can try to fix the error message:

1. Delete all directories on `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Temp\` that start with npm-.
2. `npm cache clean`
3. Run as an administrator

Ref: [npm Error : EBUSY resource busy or locked / npm | GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13461)

Comment: The problem was got solved by running the same command with "Run as Administrator" in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted all my node modules and reinstalled, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

On **Arch Linux** just run:

```
rmdir -rf node_modules
sudo pacman -S npm
npm install -g semver
sudo pacman -Sy node-gyp
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all *node_modules* and check *npmrc* file whether it's there in *C:\Users<username>* folder or not. If not, then create it and again do `npm install` followed by `npm cache clean` and `npm run start`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Yarn rather than npm

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder
2. `yarn add`
3. `npm cache verify`